# tmux can't handle short cuts that use my alt key

Tags: terminal, tmux

tmux can't handle short cuts that use my alt key

For example:

```
bind-key -n M-l next-window
bind-key -n M-h previous-window
```

I have noticed that when I type M-l and M-h in my shell I get these character: ì, è

I'm guessing that related somehow.

I'm using xterm btw.  and ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

In my .Xdefaults I added the following line:

```
XTerm*eightBitInput: true
```

Then I reran it with

```
xrdb -merge .Xdefaults
```

Now when I start up new xterms, the alt key works as it should.